# Do people get high using cat urine?

Tags: recreational-drugs

In one episode of South Park, people start getting high on cat urine. Some preliminary searches on the net show some people agreeing and some disagreeing with this fact. It's hard to say how serious people are when they answer because they don't cite sources or use sarcasm tags.

Some comments/answers from the first three searches:

> - I know this is kinda late, but    actually you can, that's where south    park got it from. But it isn't like    they showed it in the
>     show. Actually    what happens is people dip ciggs or    joints or
>     something rolled up like    that and dip it in cat pee and let it dry. Once you smoke it after that it    is suppose to intensify your
>     high or    something. I would NEVER try that. I    also heard about
>     people doing that    but dipping it in PCP, which is    stupid beyond
>     belief, I saw a youtube    video of a guy after doing that who    ran
>     into a resturant naked shoving    ice cubes up his butt and saying all
>     kinds of crazy stuff, they had him    handcuffed sitting on the ground
>     with    a bag over his face.
> - Yes. And very high. But it has to be    warm, mixed with a dog feces and    minimum one liter of it. So you need    about ten male
>     cats urine? Let me    know the ward you will be in, so I    can visit
>     you in the hospital. And    you know what. Some indigenous males    in
>     Africa get high after eating the    wives placenta. You'll never know 
>     what makes you crazy!!
> - There's no such thing. We're humans not Southpark
> - Yes you can theres an active metabolite within the urine that acts similar to that of DMT a chemical released by the pituitary gland
>     which causes humans to dream. What happens is that it produces a
>     really intense trip for about 10-15minutes then the user forgets about
>     it, so basically you have to have a pen and paper on hand once you've
>     come out of your trip. Hope you have fun

Is it actually possible to get high on cat urine? If so, is it a wide-spread practice?

Comment: Yuck! Who does that!

Comment: wait, let me try...

Comment: Do add references to this (not to the South Park episode; what you've found from your preliminary searches). Anyway, [this site](http://stopthedrugwar.org/speakeasy/2008/apr/01/southpark_11_years_exposing_drug) claims (albeit without citation) that the idea has a completely different origin: *The cat urine episode is based, in part, on reports that surfaced a few months ago about kids saving human feces, fermenting it, and then inhaling the gasses to get high.*

Comment: Using my superpowers I can detect sarcasm in the quoted messages even if they have no sarcasm tag :\ Especially in the one suggesting mix with dog feces...

Comment: @ariel Any results yet ?

Comment: Unrelated, but there is always the curious case of coffee made from beans extracted from the feces of the [civet cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopi_Luwak).

Comment: Does this mean I might have a way to profit from my used kitty litter?

Comment: The episode's drug was just a gag, they were trying to think up a funny drug epidemic.  I doubt the writers stand by the claim.

Comment: The findings of human mind is such that it will hardly react to any bio-excreta,and you can also find anything in your city, why obsessed with your cat. :P

Comment: Regarding the PCP claim.. PCP (aka phencyclidine) is a powerful dissociative similar to ketamine. Although PCP can cause feelings of "superpowers" (namely invinsibility) the claims of superhuman strength and crazy behaviour are massively over exaggerated. While a high dose can cause negative effects, they are mostly anaesthetic, as thats what PCP namely is.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This sounds like a variation on the "Jenkem" hoax. The only thing you can reliably harvest from urine (of any kind) is potassium nitrate, and ammonia. Well, and water. Ferment them, and you'll probably get methane. All these things are freely available in less repulsive forms.

Citations:
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkem)
[Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/crime/warnings/jenkem.asp)

I'd cite more "[credible](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UsNbsjpuLc)" sources, unfortunately many of them are regular news organizations who seem to believe this is a real thing. "Oh those wacky kids! What will they think of next!"

Comment: This was posted as a suggested edit by an anonymous user: "Siberian indigenous people, the Chukchi people, "harvested" the psychoactive components from Amanita Muscaria mushrooms by drinking recycled urine, and no less an authority then the greatest ethnobotanist/botanist Richard Evans Schultes wrote about it in his seminal book "Hallucinogenic Plants" (which I originally purchased at my junior high school book-fair in 1974 for $0.75) So there seems to be one more thing culled from piss than a previous post suggests, unless they are suggesting they know better than Schultes."

Comment: @SIMEL Harvesting such compounds from urine generally requires consumption of the original hallucinogenic compound directly.